# shoppingCartPaymentList() always returns empty result

Tags: soap-api-v2

I am using the following code to try to receive a list of all available payment methods:

```
$payments = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentList($sessionId, $cartId);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($payments);
echo '</pre>';
```

While I have configured payment methods in the website configuration of the shop, only an empty array is returned. I have also set a valid store view id in my `shoppingCartCreate()`, so this should be fine, too.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The price for the product I added for testing was set to 0.00 (and so was shipping), so Magento automatically applied the "Zero Subtotal Checkout" method (not sure if that´s the correct english name, using a German instance) for payments.

As I tried to set a payment method *before* retrieving a list, the returned array was emtpy (strange anyways, but well...).

I changed the price to 0.01 Euro, so the Zero Subtotal Checkout did not apply anymore. Once I did that *and* moved the `shoppingCartPaymentList()` before the `shoppingCartPaymentMethod()` all available payment methods were returned.

Answer (score 1):

$payments = $proxy->availblePaymentMethods($sessionId, $cartId);

Please try with above

Comment: That still returns an empty result.